# How to draw a dynamic Horizontal tree with expandable div?

Tags: angular, d3.js, tree

[image: Expandable div]

Using angular 5, I need to draw a horizontal tree.

where I have to implement those line which should have dynamic as every box could have expanded.

So far I have implemented those boxes but no idea how to draw those line which will bind to the boxes whenever they expanded.

I was trying to do with d3js. but as I am new in d3 I would be glad if you could give me an idea which function or method would be appropriate for that kind of line

Comment: I have no idea about d3.js but you can try PrimeNG tree. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree. There is one option for the horizontal tree.

Comment: With primefaces can i draw lines that will also move with the expandable box? @pArthsavadiya

Comment: No, but there is drag-drop functionality available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use primeng horizontal tree, which gives you same structure which you have drawn. The link is https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree.
The another library i found is ngx-graph. Please use the following link.
https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/

[image]
The Image of primeng horizontal table with expand/collapse.